# How to fix float object cannot be interpreted as an integer python

Tags: python

here is the error :

```
Converting Image to Black and White regions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\Drawing-Algorithm-master\Image
 Algorithm - Shader Type.py", line 687, in <module>
    imageToBWandSectorData()
  File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\Drawing-Algorithm-master\Image
 Algorithm - Shader Type.py", line 516, in imageToBWandSectorD
    for ypixel in range(startingy,secheight+1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

i can post file on mediafire or something

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the file where this error is happening?

Comment: One of `startingy` or `secheight` is a float and can't be used as an argument for range. Maybe convert it to `int` with `int(startingy)` for example.